# Is there a way to get WMI data into T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, wmi, monitor, wmi-query

The following is a SQL-like command used in a sample VBScript to get Biztalk suspend instances via the WMI interface.

```
select * from MSBTS_serviceinstance where ServiceStatus=4
```

MSBTS_serviceinstance is NOT a table, it is a WMI Class, as defined here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560069%28v=BTS.70%29.aspx

It is used in VBScript like this:

```
 sQuery  = "select * from MSBTS_serviceinstance where ServiceStatus=4 and ErrorId ='" & sErrorCode & "'"   
  Set intSet = GetObject("Winmgmts:!root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer").ExecQuery(sQuery)
  ' then you have to loop through the results
```

Is there a way to run a similar command from directly T-SQL.  If I could get that data and store it in a table from T-SQL, then I wouldn't have to write a C# or VBScript program, and our DBA's could also understand and help maintain the code.  This is for the purpose of monitoring and created alerts; which so far is done mostly by SQL Agent Jobs.  [Down the road a few weeks or months we might be using Orion's Solar Wind to do more monitoring, but I need a quick alert created as soon as possible.]

Comment: not tried it but sp_OACreate and sp_OAMethod might just do it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190501.aspx

Comment: You could use a CLR stored procedure, but I'm not sure why your DBAs can't understand VBScript or - even better - PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to *directly* "query" WMI classes from T-SQL. To run WMI queries, you need to leverage the WMI infrastructure, which is typically done from a .Net Framework application, a script language, etc. However, you can access WMI *indirectly* from T-SQL.

Before we get to far, a few words about `xp_cmdshell`. I am neither advocating nor decrying the enabling and usage of an extended stored procedure. This answer merely shows what is possible for a particular use case. Is it ok to enable `xp_cmdshell`? [Decide for yourself](https://www.google.com/search?q=risks%20of%20xp_cmdshell).

If it's not already enabled, [enable `xp_cmdshell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190693.aspx). We'll run `WMIC.exe` as follows, and capture the output as raw "XML" to a temp table.  Afterwards, we'll take that "XML data" and cast it to strongly typed, actual XML data, and shred it.  We get back strongly typed data in our result set, with one column for each field of the `Win32_Process` class.

Reference:  [WMI Queries From Within SQL Server...Sort Of](http://itsalljustelectrons.blogspot.com/2015/12/wmi-queries-from-within-sql-server.html)

```
CREATE TABLE #WMIC (
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    CmdOutput VARCHAR(1000)
)

INSERT INTO #WMIC (CmdOutput)
EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell 'WMIC.exe MSBTS_serviceinstance get Name,ServiceName,ServiceStatus,SuspendTime /FORMAT:RAWXML'

DECLARE @Cmd VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @Xml XML

SELECT @Cmd = @Cmd + COALESCE(w.CmdOutput, '') 
FROM #WMIC w
ORDER BY w.ID

SET @Xml = CAST(@Cmd AS XML)

SELECT
    Name = BT_Service.value('(PROPERTY[@NAME="Name"]/VALUE)[1]', 'VARCHAR(512)'),
    ServiceName = BT_Service.value('(PROPERTY[@NAME="ServiceName"]/VALUE)[1]', 'VARCHAR(512)'),
    ServiceStatus = BT_Service.value('(PROPERTY[@NAME="ServiceStatus"]/VALUE)[1]', 'INT'),
    SuspendTime = BT_Service.value('(PROPERTY[@NAME="SuspendTime"]/VALUE)[1]', 'DATETIME')
FROM @Xml.nodes('/COMMAND/RESULTS/CIM/INSTANCE') AS WmiTbl(BT_Service)
WHERE BT_Service.value('(PROPERTY[@NAME="ServiceStatus"]/VALUE)[1]', 'INT') = 4

DROP TABLE #WMIC
```

**NOTES:**

1. I don't have a server with BizTalk installed, so I couldn't test/verify the code above. There may be some issues as-is with case sensitivity...it is XML after all.
2. Don't forget to disable `xp_cmdshell` when you're done!